# Отправляю GET запрос, сервер отвечает 404 "Тело ответа будет пустым." Что нужно сделать чтоб это указать

Tags: java, get

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;



import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

/**
 *
 * @author Ewrei
 *///Ошибка
class   ErrorObj
{
    long code;
    String message;
}
//Отправка телефона
class pojo1
{
int id;

public void  setId(int p)
{
    id = p;
}
//generate setter and getters
}

public class PovtornayOtpravka {

     public static HttpClient verifiedClient(HttpClient base) {  
    try {  
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");  
        X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {  
                return null;  
            }  
            @Override  
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}  
            @Override  
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}  
        };

        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null); 
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); 
        ClientConnectionManager mgr = base.getConnectionManager();
        SchemeRegistry registry = mgr.getSchemeRegistry(); 
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, ssf)); 
        return new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, base.getParams());  
    } catch (Exception ex) {  
        ex.printStackTrace();  
        return null;  
    }  
}  


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
  pojo1 poj = new pojo1();
  poj.setId(159184727);
  Gson         gson2          = new Gson();
  StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson2.toJson(poj));


 String url = "https://protaxi-brest.hivelogin.ru:443/api/client/mobile/1.0/registration/resubmit&id=" + poj.id;

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client = verifiedClient(client);
HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url);


HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

//final GitPolz polz = gson.fromJson(response.getEntity().(), GitPolz.class);
System.out.println("Response Code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

 //String httpResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it. Вопросы тут принято задавать на русском языке.

Comment: Возможно шаманить придется с url encode

Comment: А вот текст ошибки переводить не следовало)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `String url = "https://protaxi-brest.hivelogin.ru:443/api/client/mobile/1.0/registration/resubmit&id=" + poj.id;`

Вы некорректно передаёте параметр.

Строка параметров должна отделяться от пути запроса вопросительным знаком:

```
http://example.org/path?param=value&param2=value2
```

Попробуйте так:

```
String url = "https://protaxi-brest.hivelogin.ru:443/api/client/mobile/1.0/registration/resubmit?id=" + poj.id;
```